# selecting max timestamp value on a distinct select in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have data which looks like this:

```
USER_ID     ROLE            SESSION_ID  TIMESTAMP
f684d34a    VP Marketing    890485E     51:16.2
f684d34a    VP Marketing    890485E     51:13.5
f684d34a    VP Marketing    890485E     51:39.3
f684d34a    VP Marketing    890485E     51:32.2
f684d34a    VP Marketing    890485E     51:20.0
f684d34a    VP, Marketing   890485E     49:52.9
f684d34a    VP Marketing    890485E     51:17.6
f684d34a    VP Marketing    890485E     52:14.2
f684d34a    VP Marketing    890485E     51:41.3
f684d34a    VP Marketing    890485f     51:41.1
f684d34a    VP Marketing    890485f     51:41.4
```

This is a subset, but for every user_id there could be multiple `SESSION_ID` and multiple `ROLE`.

I want to get distinct combinations of user_id and session_id as well as role, but when the role is different when the user_id and session_id is the same, take the oldest role, indicated by timestamp.

Final output:

```
USER_ID     ROLE            SESSION_ID  TIMESTAMP
f684d34a    VP, Marketing   890485E     49:52.9
f684d34a    VP Marketing    890485f     51:41.1
```

So as u can see in entry 1, all the instances of user_id and session_id are distinct, but I also wanted role so I took the role of the oldest timestamp for this combination.

Comment: Isn't the oldest timestamp `51:13.5`? `51:41.1` isn't the oldest or newest.

Comment: @Barmar that one has a different session_id and its the oldest timestamp for that user_id session_id combo

Comment: I misread, I thought you were grouping by user id and role.

Comment: @Barmar any idea how to solve

Comment: Yes. I marked this as a duplicate of a question that shows how to solve it.